# Textarea is invalid on init in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have html like this:

```
<div ng-if="item.fieldType == 'TextArea'" flex="100" ng-class="{error: form[item.id].$error}" class="ng-scope error flex-100">
     <textarea name="{{item.id}}" ng-required="item.isRequired" ng-pattern="item.regexValidation" ng-model="item.value"></textarea>
    <div ng-messages="form[item.id].$error" aria-live="assertive" class="ng-active">
        <div ng-message="required" class="ng-scope">This is required!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and on init the textarea is invalid and required ng-message is shown, how can I make validation only appear on blur? I'm using angular 1.5 and angular material.

Comment: `ng-blur` call a function and evaluate the input's value in it.

Comment: leaving a comment here for future reader: required textarea will be invalid on init/load if you have a space on it like this: <textarea>[space]</textarea>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fix it by using this css (the `opacity: 0` and `margin-top: -100px` is taken from angular material)

```
textarea + [ng-messages] [ng-message] {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: -100px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
  color: red;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

textarea.ng-touched + [ng-messages] [ng-message] {
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```